# Python 3.2.5 problems with loops

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I am currently writing a program that uses the turtle to draw letters. I know about the
turtle.write function, but I want to have the turtle draw characters. Anyway, when I ask the user for an input letter, I want my code to check what letter it is, then execute a function
based on what letter was entered. Here is my code so far:

```
#this section asks for a letter to type

while 1:
    letter = input("Letter: ")
    x = ord(letter)
    print(x,letter)

#the code will call a certain function for each letter typed

if x == 97 or 65:
    a()
    print("a")
if x == 98 or 66:
    b()
    print("b")
elif x == 99 or 67:
    c()
```

(where `a()`, `b()`, `c()` are previously defined functions to draw that letter)

The problem lies when I make my if statement. The output is only `a()`. It doesn't matter what letter I input, it always gives me `a()`. How can have my code recognize the other letters typed and execute the function along with it? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Change your conditions:

```
x == 97 or 65:
```

to

```
x == 97 or x == 65:
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if x == 97 or 65:
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. It's equal to:

```
if (x == 97) or 65:
```

Which is clearly not what you wanted.

Change it to this:

```
if x == 97 or x == 65:
```

Or use the `in` operator instead:

```
if x in (97, 65):
```

And the same thing with another conditions!

This should fix it, hope it helps!

Comment: -1: That statement is *not* equivalent to `if x == (97 or 65)`.  It is equivalent to `if (x == 97) or 65`

Comment: @roippi Just realized that, fixed.

Comment: `if (x == 97) or 65` isn't "invalid," it`s just always true.

Comment: @kindall sorry, better fix my english haha

Answer (score 0):

```
x = letter.lower()

if x == 'a':
    a()
    print(x)
elif x == 'b':
    b()
    print(x)
elif x == 'c':
    c()
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question (others have), but in Python when you want to call functions based on a condition; another pattern is to use a dictionary.

Since functions are just like any other name, they can be assigned as values in a dictionary, here is an example on how your code would look like:

```
func_map = {97: a, 98: b, 99: c}
letter_code = ord(lower(letter))
if letter_code in func_map:
    func_map[letter_code]()
```

Since you are running the same function, there is no need to check the letter twice; you can just map the lower or upper case code (in my example, I have mapped the lower case code).

The `if` condition checks if the key existing in the dictionary `func_map`. By default when you loop over dictionaries, they return their keys:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> for i in d:
...     print(i)
...
a
b
```

So what we are checking is if the code exists in the dictionary, then we get the value for that code; which is the function object, and then call it with `()`.  This might look strange, but since functions are just like any other name in Python, you can reassign them to other names:

```
>>> def a():
...   print('I am A')
...
>>> b = a
>>> b()
I am A
```